# Tkinter was installed with Python 3.6.0 but is now not importing and cannot pip install/uninstall (Windows 7)

Tags: python, tkinter

I remember the dialog box prompting me with a checklist which included Tkinter. I did not uncheck the box. This is the first time I have tried to import Tkinter after this install and get the standard "module not installed" error.

When I go to install using `pip install Tkinter` I get a message saying that it could not find a version that satisfies the requirement. No matching distribution found.

If I don't have to re-install Python that would be great, has anybody ever encountered this before/know what could cause this?

Comment: Did you try `import Tkinter` or `import tkinter` (the latter is correct)?

Comment: it seems that you have not installed the complete Python packages, you can install python using Anaconda environment and then install IPython(Jupyter notebook) that provides a powerful shell and also necessary packages.

Comment: You can't install tkinter with pip

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall your  python ans install the new Python 3.7.2 on the official website !
Your  packtage will be  complete !
If  it's still bot work, try to change the path of installation.